# Javascript stockticker : not showing data on php page

Tags: php, javascript

iam not getting any javascript errors , code is getting rendered properly only, but still server not displaying data on the page.
please check the code below .

```
 <style type="text/css">
#marqueeborder {
    color: #cccccc;
    background-color: #EEF3E2;
    font-family:"Lucida Console", Monaco, monospace;
    position:relative;
    height:20px; 
    overflow:hidden;
    font-size: 0.7em;
}
#marqueecontent {
    position:absolute;
    left:0px;
    line-height:20px;
    white-space:nowrap;
}
.stockbox {
    margin:0 10px;
}
.stockbox a {
    color: #cccccc;
    text-decoration : underline;
}
</style>

 </head>

 <body>
  <div id="marqueeborder" onmouseover="pxptick=0" onmouseout="pxptick=scrollspeed">
<div id="marqueecontent">


<?php

    // Original script by Walter Heitman Jr, first published on http://techblog.shanock.com

    // List your stocks here, separated by commas, no spaces, in the order you want them displayed:
    $stocks = "idt,iye,mill,pwer,spy,f,msft,x,sbux,sne,ge,dow,t";

    // Function to copy a stock quote CSV from Yahoo to the local cache. CSV contains symbol, price, and change
    function upsfile($stock) { copy("http://finance.yahoo.com/d/quotes.csv?s=$stock&f=sl1c1&e=.csv","stockcache/".$stock.".csv"); }

    foreach ( explode(",", $stocks) as $stock ) {

        // Where the stock quote info file should be...
        $local_file = "stockcache/".$stock.".csv";

        // ...if it exists. If not, download it.
        if (!file_exists($local_file)) { upsfile($stock); }
        // Else,If it's out-of-date by 15 mins (900 seconds) or more, update it.
        elseif (filemtime($local_file) <= (time() - 900)) { upsfile($stock); }

        // Open the file, load our values into an array...
        $local_file = fopen ("stockcache/".$stock.".csv","r");
        $stock_info = fgetcsv ($local_file, 1000, ",");

        // ...format, and output them. I made the symbols into links to Yahoo's stock pages.
        echo "<span class=\"stockbox\"><a href=\"http://finance.yahoo.com/q?s=".$stock_info[0]."\">".$stock_info[0]."</a> ".sprintf("%.2f",$stock_info[1])." <span style=\"";
        // Green prices for up, red for down
        if ($stock_info[2]>=0) { echo "color: #009900;\">&uarr;";   }
        elseif ($stock_info[2]<0) { echo "color: #ff0000;\">&darr;"; }
        echo sprintf("%.2f",abs($stock_info[2]))."</span></span>\n";
        // Done!
        fclose($local_file); 
    }
?>
<span class="stockbox" style="font-size:0.6em">Quotes from <a href="http://finance.yahoo.com/">Yahoo Finance</a></span>

</div>
</div>
 </body>
 <script type="text/javascript">

    // Original script by Walter Heitman Jr, first published on http://techblog.shanock.com

    // Set an initial scroll speed. This equates to the number of pixels shifted per tick
    var scrollspeed=2;
    var pxptick=scrollspeed;
var marqueediv='';
var contentwidth="";
var marqueewidth = "";
    function startmarquee(){
        alert("hi");
        // Make a shortcut referencing our div with the content we want to scroll
        marqueediv=document.getElementById("marqueecontent");
        //alert("marqueediv"+marqueediv);
        alert("hi"+marqueediv.innerHTML);

        // Get the total width of our available scroll area
         marqueewidth=document.getElementById("marqueeborder").offsetWidth;
        alert("marqueewidth"+marqueewidth);
        // Get the width of the content we want to scroll
         contentwidth=marqueediv.offsetWidth;
        alert("contentwidth"+contentwidth);
        // Start the ticker at 50 milliseconds per tick, adjust this to suit your preferences
        // Be warned, setting this lower has heavy impact on client-side CPU usage. Be gentle.
        var lefttime=setInterval("scrollmarquee()",50);
        alert("lefttime"+lefttime);
    }

    function scrollmarquee(){
        // Check position of the div, then shift it left by the set amount of pixels.

        if (parseInt(marqueediv.style.left)>(contentwidth*(-1)))
            marqueediv.style.left=parseInt(marqueediv.style.left)-pxptick+"px";
        //alert("hikkk"+marqueediv.innerHTML);}
        // If it's at the end, move it back to the right.
        else{
            alert("marqueewidth"+marqueewidth);
            marqueediv.style.left=parseInt(marqueewidth)+"px";
        }
    }

    window.onload=startmarquee;

</script>
</html>
```

Below is the server displayed page.

[image: Stockticker]

[image: Updated StockTicker Image]

I have updated with screenshot with your suggestion, i made change in html too, to check what is showing by child dev

Answer (score 3, accepted):

<strike>1) First move the `</body>` after your javascript.

2) Your parent `div` (id marqueeborder) has a height of 20px and overflow hidden, so the cild `div` (id marqueecontent) will be cutted, change your html to:</strike>

```
<div id="marqueeborder" onmouseover="pxptick=0" onmouseout="pxptick=scrollspeed"></div>
<div id="marqueecontent">
...
</div>
```

and replace the css for #marqueecontent `position:absolute; left:0px;` with `position: relative;`.

I hope this helps...

=== UPDATE ===

As in [my example](http://jsfiddle.net/a5vya/) you only have to move the javascript into the `<head>`.
The html doesn't need to be changed!

Comment: thanks for your suggestion, i alerted html to check, what is getting in child dev, i was supprised by it, i have added the SC, can you provde me solution for it?

Comment: Ok, the main problem are php errors. The yahoo csv can't be copied. The others are the result of this error. Exists the path `stockcache`?

Comment: you are correct,i fixed this is issue by creating the file in root directory , thanks  a lot

Answer (score 0):

looked in the original site it said :

> "If it was a problem with the stockcache directory, the script would
>   likely print “0.00 ↑0.00” for every stock entry. Rather, it looks as
>   if your HTTP server is spitting out the PHP code instead of parsing it
>   properly. This could be related to a server misconfiguration or
>   conflicting code elsewhere on the page. Unfortunately, I can’t be more
>   specific without knowing much more of the context, such as the the
>   source code of the webpage in question, server OS, HTTPD and PHP
>   version, and their configurations."

looked up in the hosting help in found that it had to have php allowed (if it was within the html), had to create an .htaccess file an add the line the hosting company gave me, after a short chat with their support the issue was solved**